# Questions and ideas that have stumped philosophers

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for questions and ideas that are seen as unresolved in philosophy. I guess nothing is actually resolved. But I mean things that are generally understood to not have been sufficiently answered.

For example, in "50 Big Ideas", Ben Dupré writes:

"Aristotle recognized the dangers inherent in Plato's strict division of body and soul...Descartes, too, was aware of the problem...Nicolas Malebranche...did not so much solve the problem as underline its seriousness. Among recent philosophers, the great majority have been content to solve the riddle of Cartesian dualism by denying it - by claiming that there is only one kind of 'stuff' in the world."

...ideally, I'm looking for a book that lays out a series of questions / thoughts that haven't been sufficiently answered, but if there is no such book then I'd like to collate a list of these things. I'm also interested in references to the different questions, if you have any -- especially good accessible introductory-style texts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_philosophy) that can get you started.

I don't know of any textbooks that are set out in this manner, but there might be some.

Comment: It would be great if you pulled some current examples from the list and explained them in greater detail here, that way if the list goes away your answer is still very helpful.